# jquery individual mouseenter for elements

Tags: jquery, vote, mouseenter

I'm working on a "up, down" voting script. When the user for example hovers over the "Up" button a tooltip should fadeIn over that respective button and say "You like this post" or whatnot. The tooltip however fades in on all buttons..

The script is longer but here is the tooltip part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.vote').mouseenter(function(e) {
        var vote_status = $(this).attr("name");
        $('.tooltip').fadeIn(200);
        if( vote_status = "up" ) {
            $('.tooltip').html('You like this post');
        } 
        if ( vote_status = "down" ) {
            $('.vp_tooltip').html('You dislike this post');
        }
})
.mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut(200);
});                                                                        
});
```

HTML..

```
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<a name="up" class="vote" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">Up</a>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
<a name="down" class="vote" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">Down</a>
```

Also for some reason it doesn't pick up whether you voted "up" or "down". On mouseenter it displays "You dislike this post" regardless. Not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tooltip` applies to both tooltips, not just the one you want. So you are fading in/out both tooltips at the same time when the mouse pointer enters/leaves just one of them. And if `<?php the_ID(); ?>` generates the same ID for both the upvote and the downvote, you would have duplicate ID's, which is not valid in HTML and will lead to problems.

I strongly recommend using HTML classes rather than `name` attributes. Did you know that you can have multiple classes on a single element? Just separate them by spaces (*e.g.* `class="vote up"`).

I would also wrap all the vote buttons in a container div (to group them together) if there will be more than one set on a page. (That way, you can give the ID to only one element and access it using `.parent().attr('id')`.)

```
<div class="votePanel">
    <div class="tooltip"></div>
    <a class="vote up">Up</a>

    <div class="tooltip"></div>
    <a class="vote down">Down</a>
</div>
```

So then your JavaScript code could check for the existence of these classes. Note that in the below code example, [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) refers to the element immediately before:

**EDIT:** I came up with [a good demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/73cZN/1/) that shows how useful the classes can be to CSS styles as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vote')
        .mouseenter(function(e) {
            var vote = $(this),
                tooltip = vote.prev();

            tooltip.fadeIn(200);
            if(vote.hasClass('up')) tooltip.html('You like this post');
            if(vote.hasClass('down')) tooltip.html('You dislike this post');
        })
        .mouseleave(function(e) {
            $(this).prev().fadeOut(200);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me eliminate the excess name attribute :-)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('.tooltip').fadeIn(200);
```

is selecting both divs. You can e.g add an `id` attribute and find them like that - here's one way:

```
    if( vote_status = "up" ) {
        $('#tooltip_up').fadeIn(200);
        $('.tooltip').html('You like this post');
    } 

<div id="tooltip_up" class="tooltip"></div>
<a name="up" class="vote" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">Up</a>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but after using the prev() function I could use the same div name for the tooltip.

Comment: Just a clarification - the `name` doesn't need to change, I added the new `id` attribute for this. Maybe you meant this, but wanted to confirm. One more thing - using `.prev()` is definitively an easy way, but is less robust - if you, for whatever reason, need to add something in between `<div>` and `<a>`, this will stop working. Anyway, glad you found a way that works as you imagined!

Answer (score 1):

When talking about the current tool tip you can use the jquery prev() function to get the previous node... so this:

```
$('.tooltip').fadeIn(200);
```

becomes:

```
$(this).prev().fadeIn(200);
```

You may as well store that in a variable since you use it twice:

```
var tooltip = $(this).prev()
```

**EDIT**

[Here is an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/85euF/1/)

Comment: In your example that you posted, you are using the assignment operator rather than equality testing (`=` vs. `==`) in the if statements, so they will always be true (all non-empty strings are). So *both* tooltips say "dislike."

Comment: +1 cool. I fixed that - I copied that error from the original post and didn't notice it.